# error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have this error in my code, here is the code:
`

```
#pragma once
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "TriviaServer.h"
#include "Validator.h"
#define PORT 8820
#define IFACE 0
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

TriviaServer::TriviaServer() 
{
    _roomIdSequence = 0;
    _socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__ " - socket"); 
    /*DataBase Build*/
}

TriviaServer::~TriviaServer()
{
    map<int, Room*>::iterator it = _roomsList.begin();
    for (it; it != _roomsList.end(); it++)
    {
        delete it->second;
    }
    map<SOCKET, User*>::iterator it2 = _connectedUsers.begin();
    for (it2; it2 != _connectedUsers.end(); it2++)
    {
        delete it2->second;
        closesocket(it2->first);
    }
    closesocket(_socket);
}

void TriviaServer::server()
{
    bindAndListen();
    thread handleMessages(&TriviaServer::handleRecievedMessages);
    handleMessages.detach();
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "accepting client..." << endl;
        accept();
    }
}

void TriviaServer::bindAndListen()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sa = { 0 };
    sa.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = IFACE;
    if (::bind(_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__ " - bind");
    cout << "binded" << endl;

    if (::listen(_socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__ " - listen");
    cout << "listening..." << endl;
}

void TriviaServer::accept()
{
    SOCKET client_socket = ::accept(_socket, NULL, NULL);
    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__);

    cout << "Client accepted !" << endl;
    // create new thread for client and detach from it
    std::thread tr(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this, client_socket);
    tr.detach();
}

void TriviaServer::clientHandler(SOCKET s)
{
    bool clientConnected = true;
    while (clientConnected)
    {
        int code = Helper::getMessageTypeCode(s);
        RecievedMessage* m = buildRecieveMessage(s, code);
        addRecievedMessage(m);
    }
}

void TriviaServer::safeDeleteUser(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    try
    {
        SOCKET soc = m->getSock();
        handleSignout(m);
        if (soc != NULL)
        {
            closesocket(soc);
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    { }
}

void TriviaServer::addRecievedMessage(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mtxRecievedMessages);
    m->setUser(getUserBySocket(m->getSock()));
    locker.lock();
    _queRcvMessages.push(m);    
    locker.unlock();
    _cond.notify_one();

}

RecievedMessage* TriviaServer::buildRecieveMessage(SOCKET s, int code)
{
    vector<string> values;
    int len;
    switch (code)
    {
    case SIGN_IN_REQUEST:
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            len = Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(s, 2);
            values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, len));
        }
        break;
    case SIGN_OUT_REQUEST:
        break;
    case SIGN_UP_REQUEST:
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            len = Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(s, 2);
            values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, len));
        }
        break;
    case AVAILABLE_ROOM_REQUEST:
        break;
    case ROOM_USERS_REQUEST:
    case ROOM_JOIN_REQUEST:
        values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, 4));
        break;
    case ROOM_LEAVE_REQUEST:
        break;
    case ROOM_CREATE_REQUEST:
        len = Helper::getIntPartFromSocket(s, 2);
        values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, len));
        values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, 1));
        values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, 2));
        values.push_back(Helper::getStringPartFromSocket(s, 2));
        break;
    case ROOM_CLOSE_REQUEST:
        break;
    case EXIT_APPLICATION:
        break;
    }

    RecievedMessage* m;
    if (!values.empty())
    {
        m = new RecievedMessage(s, code, values);
    }
    else
    {
        m = new RecievedMessage(s, code);
    }
    return m;
}
void TriviaServer::handleRecievedMessages()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mtxRecievedMessages);
    while (true)
    {
        if (_queRcvMessages.empty())
        {
            _cond.wait(locker);
        }
        switch (_queRcvMessages.front()->getMessageCode())
        {
        case SIGN_IN_REQUEST:
            handleSignin(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case SIGN_OUT_REQUEST:
            handleSignout(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case SIGN_UP_REQUEST:
            handleSignup(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case AVAILABLE_ROOM_REQUEST:
            handleGetRooms(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case ROOM_USERS_REQUEST:
            handleGetUsersInRoom(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case ROOM_JOIN_REQUEST:
            handleJoinRoom(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case ROOM_LEAVE_REQUEST:
            handleLeaveRoom(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case ROOM_CREATE_REQUEST:
            handleCreateRoom(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case ROOM_CLOSE_REQUEST:
            handleCloseRoom(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        case EXIT_APPLICATION:
            handleSignout(_queRcvMessages.front());
            break;
        }
        _queRcvMessages.pop();
    }
}

User* TriviaServer::getUserBySocket(SOCKET s)
{
    std::map<SOCKET, User*>::iterator it;
    it = find(_connectedUsers.begin(), _connectedUsers.end(), s);
    if (it != _connectedUsers.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

User* TriviaServer::handleSignin(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    int flag = true; // if wrong details
    map<string, string>::iterator it;
    map<SOCKET,User*>::iterator itConnected;
    User* login = nullptr;
    for (it = _dbUsers.begin(); it != _dbUsers.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((it->first) == ((*(m->getValues()))[0]) && (it->second) == ((*(m->getValues()))[1]))
        {
            flag = false;
            login = new User(it->first, m->getSock());
            for (itConnected = _connectedUsers.begin(); itConnected != _connectedUsers.end(); it++)
            {
                if (itConnected->second->getUsername() == login->getUsername())
                {
                    delete login;
                    login = nullptr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (login)
    {
        Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_IN_SUCCESS));
    }
    else if (flag)
    {
        Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_IN_WRONG_DETAILS));

    }
    else
    {
        Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_IN_USER_CONNECTED));
    }
    return login;
}

bool TriviaServer::handleSignup(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    //[203##username##pass##email]
    string user = (*m->getValues())[0];
    string pass = (*m->getValues())[1];
    string email = (*m->getValues())[2];

    if (!Validator::isPasswordValid(pass))
    {
        Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_PASS_ILLEGAL));
        return false;
    }
    if (!Validator::isUsernameValid(user))
    {
        Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_ILLEGAL));
        return false;
    }
    //////////////////// TEMP CODE
    map<string, string>::iterator it = _dbUsers.begin();
    for (it; it != _dbUsers.end(); it++)
    {
        if (user == it->first)
        {
            Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_EXISTS));
            return false;
        }
    }
    _dbUsers.insert(pair<string, string>(user, pass));
    //////////////////// END TEMP CODE
    //////////////////// FUTURE CODE:
    /*if (!DataBase::isUserExists(user))
    {
    Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_USERNAME_EXISTS));
    return false;
    }
    if(!DataBase::addNewUser(user, pass, email))
    {
    Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_OTHER));
    return false;
    }
    */
    Helper::sendData(m->getSock(), to_string(SIGN_UP_SUCCESS));
    return true;
}

void TriviaServer::handleSignout(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    User* u;
    if (u = m->getUser())
    {
        map<SOCKET, User*>::iterator it = _connectedUsers.begin();
        for (it; it != _connectedUsers.end(); it++)
        {
            if (it->first == u->getSocket())
            {
                delete it->second;
                closesocket(it->first);
            }
        }
        handleCloseRoom(m);
        handleLeaveRoom(m);
        //handleLeaveGame(m);
    }
}

bool TriviaServer::handleCreateRoom(RecievedMessage* m)
{
    User* curr = m->getUser();
    if (curr)
    {
        vector<string>* values = m->getValues();
        if (curr->createRoom(++_roomIdSequence, m->getUser(),(*values)[0] ,stoi((*values)[1], nullptr, 0), stoi((*values)[3], nullptr, 0), stoi((*values)[2], nullptr, 0)))
        {
            _roomsList.insert(pair<int, Room*>(_roomIdSequence, curr->getRoom()));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
bool TriviaServer::handleCloseRoom(RecievedMessage* m)
{

}
bool TriviaServer::handleJoinRoom(RecievedMessage* m)
{

}
bool TriviaServer::handleLeaveRoom(RecievedMessage* m)
{

}
void TriviaServer::handleGetUsersInRoom(RecievedMessage* m)
{

}
void TriviaServer::handleGetRooms(RecievedMessage* m)
{

}
```

`

I tried to put comments on all the '==' and '!=' to search where is the problem but the error keep showing up.

it is in this cpp file, as far as i can tell from the code (the only file i can't compile)

thanks for the help,
sorry for the long code,
Omer

Comment: Why are you searching for the location of the error in this bizarre manner? Every self-respecting C++ compiler will tell you the line number with the error, and every self-respecting text editor can position the cursor at the exact line. So, what's the problem?

Comment: You also need to reduce the program by deleting all the code that doesn't lead to the error.

Comment: You are obviously using Visual Studio.  Double click the error message and it will tell you which line it is complaining about.

Comment: i fixed it, thank u :)

Comment: clicking on it leads me to a compiler code, not my code

Comment: Please post an answer saying how you fixed it, so that the next person with this problem will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order of the includes in other headers that included,
it should be

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

and not the other way around!

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem. Your original code had them in this order.

Comment: Yeah but i included "TriviaServer.h" and in there i included another header that uses those includes, and i included there in the wrong order